# php if dropdown option value 0 then hide div

Tags: php, wordpress

as I am not experienced with php, I need some help solving my issue.

I pasted the snippet of php I believe needs editing.

```
<div class="selectBox" id="products-variation-container">
  <select class="product-variation-dropdown" name="product-variation" id="sel-product-variation">
     <option value="0"><?php _e('Select variation', 'wp-woo-leasing'); ?></option>
  </select>
</div>

<!--  <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" class="button alt" id="leasingAddItem" value="<?php _e('Add Item', 'wp-woo-leasing'); ?>" 
  data-value="<?php _e('Add Item', 'wp-woo-leasing'); ?>" />-->

 </div>
</div>
<div class="leasing-single-container" >
    <div class="leasing-col1" >
        <div id="product-description" class="product-description"></div>
        <div id="product-price-details" class="product-price-details"></div>
    </div>
```

My issue is that I want my code to be like:

```
<select class="product-variation-dropdown" name="product-variation" id="sel-product-variation">
     <option value="0"><?php _e('Select variation', 'wp-woo-leasing'); ?>
```

If option value = "0" then hide the following div, upon loading site, since default is value is 0.

```
<div id="product-description" class="product-description"></div>
```

I hope you understand my question, and I hope that you can guide me to approaching this issue, thanks.

Comment: <option value=''>Please Select</option>.. you can use something like this instead.. Instead trying for zero

Comment: use a conditional statement or ternary operator; the latter being a more streamlined solution

Comment: I don't get your question, do you want to hide the div when ever the option with value 0 is selected or is it just upon load of the page that if the selected option value is 0 then hide the div?

Comment: @Epodax Just upon load of the page is good. I read that maybe PHP is not the right solution?

Comment: Upon page load php is just fine, however if you want it to change after that you'll need to use ajax, read Fredd's suggestion.

Comment: @Epodax 
Problem is my knowledge of php, would this work?
                      <?php 
                      if($_POST['lease-product'] == 0) {
                        <style type="text/css">#product-description"{
                          display:none;
                      }</style>
                      ?>

Comment: Try, nothing is gonna explode by you trying, the worst thing that is gonna have is that you're gonna get a error or something doesn't show as it should, but you can remove your "test" code again.

Comment: @Epodax hehe that did definitely not work. Can you recommend where i can learn this. Basically it sounds simple when i think about it. If value option is 0 then display:none. The syntax is my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124545/discussion-between-mads-hjorth-and-epodax).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to show and hide div on basis of select value.

Wordpress have already included jquery file, so you no need to add it.
(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Here is code you can use:

```
  <div class="selectBox" id="products-variation-container">
  <select class="product-variation-dropdown" name="product-variation" id="sel-product-variation" onchange="getval();">
 <option value="0">Select Option</option>
 <option value="1">Select Option1</option>
 </select>
 </div>
<div class="leasing-single-container" >
<div class="leasing-col1" >
    <div id="product-description" class="product-description">dgsdgsdgsdgsdgsd</div>
    <div id="product-price-details" class="product-price-details"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var sel = jQuery('select[name=product-variation]').val();
            if(sel == 0) {
                    jQuery('#product-description').attr('style', 'display:none');
            }
            jQuery('#sel-product-variation').on('change', function() {
              var sel = jQuery('select[name=product-variation]').val();
                    if(sel == 0) {
                            jQuery('#product-description').attr('style', 'display:none');
                    }
                    else {
                            jQuery('#product-description').attr('style', 'display:block');
                    }
            });

    });
</script>
```

Let me know incase of any concern for the same.